# SonarQube Cannot analyze file - Unsuppored Tag in JSP

Tags: sonarqube

I'm running sonar:sonar to analyze my code base and hit the below exception for a few of jsp pages. We are on sonar 5.1.2.

We have custom tags so wondering if there is a way for me to link our own tags or get rid of this exceptino? The mvn job will still run successfully, but not sure how accurate the analysis will be with these exceptions on jsp pages.

```
[ERROR] [15:50:44.120] Cannot analyze file /xxx/xxx/xxx/Common.jsp
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.isUnsupportedTag(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.startElement(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scanElementTag(HtmlAstScanner.java:118) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scanElement(HtmlAstScanner.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scan(HtmlAstScanner.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scan(HtmlAstScanner.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.web.core.WebSensor.analyse(WebSensor.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch1679801380261302841.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the part of the JSP page that makes the analysis fail?

Comment: Usually we include jspf/js in other jsp pages, but there are cases we include jsp pages. The reported jsp page is one of the jsp pages to be included in other jsp pages. We have java code pieces and js code in that page. The page is mainly to be included as a js section so there are not js tags. Guess the issue is sonar not being able to parse js code w/o <javascript>tags. I will fix our code and check again. Thanks!